# Need to calculate values for a cell based on surrounding landscape

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, raster-calculator

I have a raster file with the urban development of a county mapped out (values: 1=urban 0=not urban). I also have a raster file with several blocks of forested land, each block of land has its own numeric identifier and 2-1000 cells per block. The 2 rasters have the same cell size.

I need to calculate, for each individual cell in the forested lands layer, what percentage of the land within 4km is covered by urban development.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question/tags to include the software you are using.

Comment: Have a look at the Focal Statistics tool in the help file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Focal Statistic tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm), in conjunction with a couple of conditional statements in [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000zn000000.htm) will do what you are needing.

1. First, get a count of all non-urban cells within the 4km neighborhood:

   Using raster calculator:

   ```
   nonurban_raster = Con("land_use_raster"==0, "1", "")
   ```

   Then with focal stat tool:

   ```
   sum_nonurban_raster = FocalStatistics("land_use_raster", NbrCircle(100, "CELL"), "SUM", "NODATA")
   ```
2. Next, get the count of only urban cells, first by isolating urban cells with conditional statement in raster calculator.

   ```
   urban_raster = Con("Land_use_raster"==1, 1, "")
   ```

   and then with focal stat tool.

   ```
   sum_urban_raster = FocalStatistics("urban_raster", NbrCircle(100, "CELL"), "SUM", "NODATA")
   ```
3. Finally, get your percentage by using raster calculator.

   ```
   pct_urban_raster = "sum_urban_raster" / ("sum_nonurban_raster" + sum_urban_raster")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have 2 questions 1) is "land_use_raster" my forested lands raster or my urban areas raster? 2) when I use the forested lands raster the output from step 1 is a file with nothing in it (no attribute table).

Comment: yes, land_use_raster contains your urban/non-urban binary, and will be the Input raster for the first focal statistic step.  Are you running these from the command prompt or from ArcToolbox? Also, can you edit your question to include your raster cell sizes?

Comment: Okay, I just ran the first step with the urban/non_urban raster and it failed to execute. I'm running this from the raster calculator tool. My cell sizes are 40m x 40m for all rasters.

Comment: Yes, I have the spatial analyst extension running.

Comment: Okay, take a look at the link for the Focal Stat.  It is a tool in the spatial analyst toolbox.  It is run independently from the raster calculator.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Aha! I guess I misunderstood you, my bad. Using Focal Stat and raster Calculator this is working better. Step 1 and Step 2a worked great, but step 2b and step 3, while they ran fine, have output rasters that are blank (raster attribute table does not exist).

Comment: Okay, I was misusing the focal stat tool.  Since there is no COUNT function, use the raster calc to separate urban and nonurban.  check out the updated steps.

Comment: Okay, I tried the first step. For some reason I'm getting a message back from raster calculator saying "not supported"

Comment: My apologies, we need to give the two raster calculator steps an appropriate expression.  I've updated it again.

Comment: Hi, still getting the "not supported" error. Thank you for all of the help. If I'm understanding the process here (I might not be) Steps 1a and 2a are creating a raster file with just the urban areas, and a second with just the non-urban areas correct? Maybe I can convert this to polygons and create and urban and a non-urban file and then switch back?

Comment: Uninstalled and then re-installed GIS - it's working fine now.